# Returning custom error response in Web API

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.0

I am working on a Web API application and have a requirement that if a operation is unsuccessful return error code like 401/403/500 and along with that error message in format of {"error":"Invalid Key."}. I have implemented that by calling CreateErrorResponse as follows

```
    this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new HttpError("Invalid Key."))
```

This returns {"Message":"Invalid Key."}, but I want "Error" rather than "Message" as the key.

How can I change the "message" to "error" when returning response

Comment: You could return a dynamic object with `CreateResponse`, e.g. `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,                                                                       new {Error = "Invalid key"});`